# In Django Admin, can I lay out the list of objects according to foreign key (create headings and group objects under corresponding headings)?

Tags: django

I have 2 models, Chapter and Element. Chapters consist of elements.

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...

class Element(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="elements")
    # ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['index_number']
```

There are many elements, each belongs to a particular chapter.
`index_number`determines the position of an element in its chapter.

In Django Admin, can I customize the display of the list of elements ('Select element to change' page) so that it would display headings (like 'fieldsets' headings, but basically chapter titles) and group the elements according to a chapter that they belong to?

The desired output would look something like that:

```
Chapter 1 title
--------------------------
elm1_1
elm1_2
--------------------------
Chapter 2 title
--------------------------
elm2_1
elm2_2
--------------------------
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `templates` dir create `admin` dir, inside `admin` create another dir with the name of your app finally in the last created dir create a dir with the name of your `model`, in your case it will be `element`. At the end you should have:

```
templates/admin/app_name/element/
```

Now to change how elements are listed, you need to override the `change_list.html` template. You can do that by copying `contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html` to the `templates/admin/my_app/element/` dir then do the changes you want on your version. More on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

To make this easier you may need to override the default queryset of Django admin, you can do that by:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        #your grouping goes here
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I'm looking at the `change_list.html` template and there is `{% result_list cl %}` block that apparently is responsible for outputting the table with elements.
How can I customize that block?